# How to make a GitHub PR separate from a previous one?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repository and git cloned it. I made some changes, I made a commit (in the main branch) and I pushed to my repository on GitHub. After that, I made a pull request on the upstream.

But now I want to work on another thing from upstream/main and make another pull request. However, I don't want this new PR to include the commit of my previous PR. If I make a new branch now, the commit that I made on the main branch will also be included.

What is the correct workflow?

Comment: Create the new branch from the remote one instead of the local branch: `git checkout -b some-new-branch origin/main`. It would have been better if you had kept the local `main` on top `origin/main` instead of committing on it.... it's not like forbidden.... but if you are used to work with local branches that track the remote ones, you should not put local stuff in them.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a new branch for each PR, precisely so that you can do other work independently of the branch which is now associated with your PR. You generally want your local `main` (or `master` for older repositories) to be identical to the upstream you forked from.

To fix the situation, just create a new branch at the point you want it, i.e. probably at your current `HEAD`, then push that.

```
git checkout -b you-pr-1
git push yourfork you-pr-1
```

(where `yourfork` is the `git remote` pointing to your fork; probably `origin`), then create your PR from the branch `you-pr-1` in your Github repo.

To sync upstream's `main` back to yours, try

```
# Rewind back to upstream's main
git checkout upstream/main
# Create a new local main branch from here, replacing the previous local one
git checkout -B main
```

(where obviously `upstream` and `main` might be something else. This assumes `upstream` is the name of the `git remote` you originally forked from.)

If you already created a PR then you are kind of locked in until the PR is closed. Perhaps you can apologize and close the PR and create a new one properly from a branch if you don't want to wait it out.

The output from `git log` helpfully shows you which commits various remotes are associated with. If you didn't before, probably `git add remote upstream` with the repo URL of the upstream repo you forked from so that you can reference it and, if necessary, pull etc from it. `git remote -v` shows your existing remotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new branch from the main of your forked repo excluding the last commit. You can achieve this using the git log command. Use git log to see the commit hash before the last commit. Then go to the main branch and create a new branch as below

git checkout -b new-branch commit-hash